# Group By & parition by in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, window-functions

I know this may be very silly question but I will appreciate any help or hint to solve this question.

Below is my test data

```
Create Table #Test (Id Int Identity(1,1), Category Varchar(100), DateTimeStamp DateTime)



    Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 01:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 02:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 03:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 04:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 05:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 06:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 07:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 08:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 09:00:13.503')
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c2','2019-08-13 10:00:13.503')  
        Insert into #Test (Category,DateTimeStamp) values ('c1','2019-08-13 11:00:13.503')
```

This is My Query

```
Select *,row_number() over (partition by category order by datetimestamp)
        From #Test
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

[image: cURRENT OUTPUT]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to find the changes in `category`.  You can use `lead()` and `lag()` for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(category) over (order by id) as prev_category,
             lead(category) over (order by id) as next_category
      from #test t
     ) t
where prev_category is null or prev_category <> category or
      next_category is null or next_category <> category
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6d61fbe751f89e42d11d67649927903) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hello sir @Gordon Linoff, Actually small change i need i need to partition on two columns Category1 and Category2 how can i do it ? what change should i do it here

Comment: @HardikParmar . . . If you cannot figure out how to adapt this answer (hint:  you can generate a separate value for each column) you should ask a *new* question.  This question is clearly about a single category and it has already been answered.

Comment: @Hardik Ask your whole question up front, don't dumb it down just so people have to change their answer, which answered the original, dumbed-down version.